# How do I start animating applications in winforms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation

I would like to get some references or examples on how to animate my `winform` applications.

When I click on a button it should transform group of objects to small or big, move it's position, change the color, etc. I would also accept a library as an answer.

Comment: Do you have to use Winforms? WPF is ideal for this...

Comment: i am nobibe to WPF so thinking to work on winforms... starting of wpf is also gr8 idea...

Comment: DEFINITELY grab a WPF book, tutorial or whatever and do your project in WPF. What you're describing is EXACTLY what WPF is for.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "objects"? Do you mean objects on the form or do you mean shapes? How many shapes, etc. I have a answer that requires **no libraries** and is fairly **easy**, **but I don't know if it would fit *your* situation**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [dot-net-transitions](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) and I have no issues with is so far. It contains 8 type of animations and basically allows you to animate any controls with them.

> **TransitionType_Linear** is a linear animation with objects moving at a
>   constant rate throughout the transition.
>
> **TransitionType_Acceleration** starts the transition at zero velocity and
>   builds up at a constant rate of acceleration to be at full-speed by
>   the end of the transition.
>
> **TransitionType_Deceleration** starts the transition at full-speed and
>   decelerates at a constant rate to be at zero velocity by the end of
>   the transition.
>
> **TransitionType_CriticalDamping** is a declerating transition, using an
>   exponentially decaying velocity. It is good (for example) for
>   animating properties such as needles on dials.
>
> **TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut** starts at zero velocity and accelerates
>   until halfway through the transition, then decelerates back to zero
>   velocity by the end of the transition.
>
> **TransitionType_Bounce** accelerates to the destination value by halfway
>   through the transition and then decelerates back to the original value
>   by the end. This is similar to acclerating downwards with gravity and
>   then bouncing back against gravity.
>
> **TransitionType_ThrowAndCatch** is the counterpart of the Bounce
>   transition above. It decelerates to the destination value by halfway
>   through the transition and then acclerates back to the original value
>   by the end.
>
> **TransitionType_Flash** lets you specify a number of flashes and the time
>   for each flash. Each flash animates the properties to their
>   destination value and back again using an ease-in-ease-out transition.

They have a decent documentation on how you can implement the features, you can find it at http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/wiki/CodingWithTransitions

Also they have an [.exe sample](http://dot-net-transitions.googlecode.com/files/TransitionsSample_1_2.zip) that basically shows all the animations so you know what to expect.